# Powerpoint saving error "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When attempting to save a file in powerpoint 2010 I get the following error:

[image]

Are there any recommended step to ensure I do not lose the open file?

Comment: Copy the contents of the file and paste into a new file. That should be the first step

Comment: @pun Thanks, yes done that - get the same error.

Comment: Try [this fix then](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2387587) & does it change if you change the fonts used in the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the "*This file is corrupted and cannot be opened*" error message, set component security settings back to the default settings.

Do as shown below :

- Start Run and enter **dcomcnfg** & press enter
- Expand Component Services → Navigate to Computers → Right Click My Computer and select Properties
- Open the Default Properties tab, and then set the following values:

`Default Authentication Level: Connect`

`Default Impersonation Level: Identify`

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/Library/Images/2704885.png))</sub>

- Click OK & try saving the document again

Source : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2387587

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the presentation file with a different extension - worked for me (only thing was I had to copy the comments back from the original file to the new one).